# Dynamic or static import of json in browser with ESM

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dynamic-import, es6-modules

I have the following example running without the JS having a bundler on top of it.

```js
// index.js
;(async () => {
  const mod = await import('/index.json')

  console.log(mod)
})()
```

```
{
  "file": "index.json"
}
```

Chrome 80 fails to load the json with

> Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "application/json". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

Firefox 73 fails in a similar way:

> Loading module from “http://127.0.0.1:8080/index.json” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“application/json”).

Is this behavior surmountable?

Comment: Even if your server were to provide that content with the mime-type `text/javascript`, that import would still not work as such in a browser because it is not syntactically valid JavaScript. I suggest you stick with `fetch` for the time being.  `const r = await fetch('/index.json'); const json = await r.json(); const o = JSON.parse(json);`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Import Assertions](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-import-assertions) are now stage 3 as of writing.

```js
import json from "./foo.json" assert { type: "json" };

// or

import("foo.json", { assert: { type: "json" } });
```

would be the syntax for pulling in a JSON file with ESM.

Comment: it's not yet shipped in firefox, follow https://github.com/mozilla/standards-positions/issues/373 or https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1777526

Answer (score 7):

You can't directly import JSON using an ES6 import.  You need to export it from a JS file:

```js
// module.js
export default {
  "foo": { "bar": "baz" }
};
```

```js
// index.js
;(async () => {
  const mod = await import('/module.js')

  console.log(mod)
})()
```

Comment: I know I'm splitting hairs, but the JSON string of your JS object above would be: `'{ "foo" : { "bar" : "baz" } }'`.

Comment: I accept your splitting of the hairs and have amended this answer

Comment: Hah! Just as I was beginning to regret being so pedantic and seriously considering deleting my comment above. That's cheered me up enormously. All's well that ends well. Great stuff.

Comment: This is a fine solution to the specific problem in the OP, but you aren't dealing with JSON anymore. `module.js` in your example doesn't involve JSON.

Comment: @AluanHaddad is right, but there is simply no avoiding this sort of workaround _until_ [JSON Modules](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-json-modules) finally get the green light.

Comment: @Rounin yes, and that will be a while. It's a crying shame the module registry API was dropped from the loader spec. But, I would argue that it's better to just use `fetch` to load JSON, especially with [top-level-await](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await) already implemented in many environments.

Comment: I am currently working with a set-up which collects a number of files and serialises them as a single JSON package which can be `fetch`-ed. I think I will try taking the serialised output and saving it _twice_: as a JSON which can be `fetch`-ed _and also_ as the `module.js` format @DanielBank outlines above, which can be `import`-ed. Consumers will then have the choice between `fetch`-ing the JSON or `import`-ing the JS.

Comment: That's a good idea. If you intend it for general consumption, I would avoid combining the files. You don't want people using named imports from such a module. To maintain the abstraction over `import` and `fetch`, you'll likely need to cache the fetch responses. Just my thoughts.